# Spring Data Elasticsearch - Is Inner Hit supported at root level on query?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use [ElasticsearchOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.operations) to write a query like this one:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "dialogLines",
            "query": {
              "match_phrase": {
                "dialogLines.text": {
                  "query": "No problem"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "movieId",
    "inner_hits" : {
        "name": "by_movie",
        "collapse" : {"field" : "boundaryGroup"},
        "sort": [{ "boundaryStartInMillis": "desc" }],
        "size": 6
    }
  }
}
```

I know `NestedQuery` supports `innerHit(InnerHitBuilder innerHitBuilder)`, but the root level query of type `NativeSearchQuery` doesn't have that method.

**Is there a way to write this query using ElasticsearchOperations?**

I'm on version `org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:3.2.9.RELEASE`

Running Elasticsearch `v6.8.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a query using `NativeSearchQuery`, you normally use

```
Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
  .withQuery(queryBuilder)
  .build();
```

The `queryBuilder` argument is any implementation of `org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder`, so you can use any of the Elasticsearch query builders that you like.

**Edit 29.09.2020**:

`NativeSsearchQuery` supports a collapse field with the `NativeSearchQueryBuilder.withCollapseField(String)` method. But there is no support for the inner hits of a collapse field yet.
I created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-939 to address that.

Comment: Right, but if I want to have `innerHits` at the top level (not as part of the query) there's no method to do so in `NativeSearchQuery`, `withCollapseField` only takes a field name. I found that `org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder#SearchSourceBuilder()` does have a `collapse` method that takes a `CollapseBuilder` but that functionality doesn't seem to be exposed in Spring Data Elasticsearch

Comment: YES. Functionality doesn't seem to be exposed in Spring Data Elasticsearch.